# Pen does not show the strokes for circular motion

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

I use a Wacom One table and Photoshop. If I put the pen on the tablet and try to draw a straight line, Photoshop immediately draw the line as I move my hand. However, if I put the pen on the tablet and start to draw in circular motion as to fill the area where the pen touched the tablet, it does not show my coloring until I take the pen off the tablet. How can I fix it? I want as I am filling a small area Photoshop shows the paint as I move the pen.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it *could* be low RAM, *or* an inadequate graphics card, or *both*... Photoshop is having trouble literally "keeping up" with what you're painting.

Test if it's low resources by doing the same thing with a *far* smaller document, with a *far smaller* brush size - with more frequent saves.

Do you see a change in the behaviour?

If yes, if there's a noticeable improvement, then you have a low resources issue.

Comment: Why would anybody be low on memory resources this day and age? I mean i haven't seen a computer with less than 4 gigabytes of memory in nearly one and a half decade. And most computers intended to use for work have a had 8 to 32 gigabytes of memory and  real workstations frequently more then that.

Comment: When OP is listing "draw in circular motion as to fill the area" as the activity in which their PS is having trouble keeping up, I tend to intuit that they *might* not be working in their primary field, and *might* not have a workstation.

Comment: Does not matter what you do even cheap ass home computers come with more than enough memory.. really even 40$ computers have gigabytes of ram